# Why state of the art network didn't perform well on Fashion MNIST

Tags: python, keras, resnet

When I tried to use RestNet50 with all layers frozen to classify Fashion MNIST dataset, I could only get around 78% training accuracy and 41% prediction accuracy. Below is the code snippet:

```py
from keras import optimizers
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from keras.layers import Activation, Flatten, Dense
from keras.models import Model

(x, y), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

dat_train, dat_val, train_lbs, val_lbs = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=10000, random_state=42)

... # transform dat_train, dat_val, x_test from shapes (28, 28, ) to (32, 32, 3) and re-scale to value range [0, 1], also one hot encoding train_lbs, val_lbs, y_test to shape (, 10)

resnet50_base = ResNet50(include_top=False, 
                         weights='imagenet', 
                         input_shape=(32, 32, 3))          

for layer in resnet50_base.layers:  
    layer.trainable = False     

base_out = resnet50_base.output                             
base_out = Flatten()(base_out)                             
base_out = Dense(128)(base_out)                             
base_out = Activation("relu")(base_out)                   
preds = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(base_out)          

model = Model(inputs=resnet50_base.input, outputs=preds) 

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",            
                optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005),       
                metrics=["accuracy"])
```

It produced this result
[image: Result of training ResNet50 on Fashion MNIST]

Did I do something wrong or ResNet50 was not suited for the Fashion MNIST datatset?

Comment: your learning rate is too low. train for more epochs. Try to use techniques like early stopping and reduceLRonPlateau in Keras to get finetuned training. You may start off with a 0.001 learning rate for adam

Comment: Also the model is overfitting on the data. The training acc is too high while the validation accuracy is too low

Comment: Hi @user239457, thanks for your response. I realised that my model was overfitted but unsure why despite having 50K training samples. Probably it's due to lower learning rate and epochs as suggested by you. Will test it. Thanks

Comment: Why did you add another Dense layer of size 128 for fine-tuning ?

Comment: Because all ResNet50 base was set non-trainable so I thought I need at least a trainable layer to suit the Fashion dataset. Was that advisable? The reason for with and without that added Dense layer?

Comment: Well the last activation layer is trainable so it's enough to have this one as the only trainable layer. Intuitively it's just a new way to "combine" the features extracted from ResNet.

Comment: Did you mean Dense(10, activation="softmax") was trainable? I thought it couldn't be  because it didn't have the linear transformation `z = w*a + b`? Assume it was, why shouldn't I add Dense(128)?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can see my repo https://github.com/rushu570/Fashion_Mnist to understand how it works

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)